# Returning Nullable<NumericMatrix> from Rcpp to R results in segfault

Tags: r, rcpp

Using Rcpp, I wrote a C++ function that returns a ´Nullable<NumericMatrix>`. Calling this function repeatedly from R crashes my R session on my windows machine and leads to a segfault error when I run it on a Linux server.

The NumericMatrix itself is generated by another C++ function and then "wrapped" in the ´Nullable<NumericMatrix>`. It seems that the error only occurs when there is some more computation going on inside the C++ function before the value gets returned to R. The error itself seems to happen once R is trying to access the returned object. The error does not happen every time the C++ function is called. But if I call it multiple times a crash is almost certain.

Here's a bit of code that once I sourceCPP it crashes almost every time:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


NumericMatrix fun() {
  NumericMatrix m (10, 10);
  std::fill(m.begin(), m.end(), 42);
  return m;
}

int otherCall() {
  NumericVector v(1000);
  std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 7);
  return v.length();
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Nullable<NumericMatrix> returnNullableObject(int num_it) {
  Nullable<NumericMatrix> object = R_NilValue;

  object = Nullable<NumericMatrix>(fun());

  for (int i = 0; i < num_it; i++) {
    otherCall();
  }

  return object;
}


/*** R
test <- function(n) {
  val <- returnNullableObject(1000L)
  is.matrix(val)
}

for (i in seq_len(100L)) test()

*/
```

Am I using the `Nullable` class wrong? It crashes on R 3.6.1 as well as on R 4.0.1

```
> devtools::session_info()
- Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  German_Germany.1252         
 ctype    German_Germany.1252         
 tz       Europe/Berlin               
 date     2020-06-16                  

- Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 backports     1.1.7   2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 callr         3.4.3   2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 cli           2.0.2   2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 devtools      2.3.0   2020-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 digest        0.6.25  2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 fs            1.4.1   2020-04-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 glue          1.4.1   2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 lattice       0.20-41 2020-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.1)
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 Matrix        1.2-18  2019-11-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.1)
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 pkgbuild      1.0.8   2020-05-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 processx      3.4.2   2020-02-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 ps            1.3.3   2020-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 R6            2.4.1   2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 remotes       2.1.1   2020-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 rlang         0.4.6   2020-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 rstudioapi    0.11    2020-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 testthat      2.3.2   2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 usethis       1.6.1   2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
 withr         2.2.0   2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
```

Comment: Maybe keep it simpler and just return a `SEXP` that is _either_ `R_NilValue` or a value?

Comment: That's basically how I've worked around the issue. I was just wondering if there is a 'correct' way of doing this?

Comment: R gives us one and only one interface:  `SEXP .Call("myfunction", SEXP a, SEXP b, ...)`.  We wrote `Nullable<>()` for more flexibility on the _input_ side. I don' think we ever said you could use for a return value...

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks for the clarification

Comment: Yes, it's not all that obvious, and maybe I'll try to add a line to the docs.  But in brief on the _input_ side we have the object and can still do things with it, conditionally.  Once you hand it back to R _it only sees a C data structure_ and there is simply nothing nullable there....

Comment: To me, the issue seems to be that if the `Nullable` object is the only reference to the NumericMatrix, its allocated memory is no longer protected from reuse/garbage collection. Simply replacing `Nullable<...>` with SEXP produces the same crash. In that case the reason seems more obvious though, since there is obviously nothing left that protects the object from the garbage collector. Replacing `Nullable<...>` with `RObject` fixes the issue.

Comment: @philipp, you should post your solution as answer.

Comment: The returning function signature needs to be `SEXP` and the returned object needs to be `SEXP` (which is more or less the same as `RObject`).  Once you do that the rest of you program is mostly ... unrelated other stuff.  And with a proper return object there is obviously also no segfault.....

Comment: Ok, but just to be clear, this version of the function still crashes: 
`SEXP returnNullableObject(int num_it) {
  SEXP object = R_NilValue;
  object = fun();
  for (int i = 0; i < num_it; i++) {
    otherCall();
  }
  return object;
}`

Comment: Yes, there are many ways _you_ can shoot yourself in the foot with C++ and C.  _Returning a temporary from inside a function_ is one time-tested method.  I just don't understand why you continue to paint _a basic and well-understood programming error_ as a bug or issue in Rcpp.  It's not.  It's how you use it that creates the issue.

Comment: Sorry, if it came across that way, I am really not trying to paint this as a bug or issue in Rcpp. I was just trying to wrap my head around the root cause of this and trying to make sure that I understand your comments. Btw, Rcpp is a great package and I really appreciate the time and effort you put into maintaining the package and answering (apparently somewhat stupid) questions such as mine.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: Use `Nullable<>` only for function inputs and nothing else. Replacing `Nullable<>` with `RObject` in the example above fixes the issue:

```
RObject returnNullableObject(int num_it) {
  RObject object = R_NilValue;

  object = fun();

  for (int i = 0; i < num_it; i++) {
    otherCall();
  }

  return object;
}
```

Thank you Dirk for your comments and clarification regarding the intended use of `Nullable<>`!